# In what charset is 0xE1 an "a" with an umlaut?

Tags: character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I am trying to identify an extended ascii charset where 0xE1 is an "a" with an umlaut (8859-1 character E4)
and 0xF5 is a "u" with an umlaut (8859-1 character FC).
Has anyone seen this charset before?  It quite possibly dates back to the 80's.

Comment: A good way to search for charset for which you know single char is to use a search engine with the format from these Unicode mapping tables. E.g.: ["0x00e4 # LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS"](http://www.google.de/search?q="0x00e4+%23+LATIN+SMALL+LETTER+A+WITH+DIAERESIS") will get you lots of results. ([Diaresis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic)) is another term for umlaut.) In contrary, for "0x00e1 # LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS" Google has no results, so your charset is either rather unknown or doesn't exist. :-(

Comment: @Max: It's not an Unicode character, so you will likely find nothing in the Unicode mapping tables :) In Unicode, all characters have the same codepoint regardless of the Unicode-compatible character encoding used (that's where "Unicode" stands for).

Comment: I know about Unicode, but there are mapping tables provided by "unicode.org" to help you mapping **other** charsets **to** unicode. And these mapping tables are very helpful to find other charsets as well.

Comment: ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/

Comment: @Max: Ah right, you mean the non-Unicode mapping tables which happen to be hosted on unicode.org. Nevermind my comment then.

Comment: Tag [tag:german] removed as part of the [2012 cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, there are no standard ASCII character sets which use those symbols.  Here is a list of the standard character sets: http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/csettables.html

However, the character set you referenced is in fact used for interfacing with some LEDs, for example HT1632-compliant LEDs use the same character set:  http://blog.thiseldo.co.uk/wp-filez/USB_HT1632_Matrix.pde

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I believe this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

These are in the commonly used ISO-8859-1 character set, also known as latin-1.